# Existence of a linear transformation with a specific value at a specific point

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ be a linear space, and let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $L$ such that $x\neq 0$. I want to show that there exists a lineat transformation $T$ on $L$ such that $T(x)=y$. At first glance, I have thought that the question is simple and defining a linear transformation on the basis elements and extending it to all space might work, but I could not figure it out. The complexity that I could not solve is that the linear combinations of $x$ and $y$ can have different basis vectors with non-zero coefficients. If you can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Without loss of generality, suppose $y\neq 0$.  (*If $y=0$, just take $T$ to be the zero operator*).  You should be able to come up with two bases for $L$ such that in the first $x$ is among the basis vectors and in the second $y$ is among the basis vectors and organize each so that they are ordered first in their respective bases.  (*Apply GramSchmidt if need be to see this*).  Per the definition of a basis, you can have $T(v)=T(\alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 b_2 + \alpha_3b_3+\dots+\alpha_n b_n)$ and map this to $\alpha_1 y$